# Why $S^TS=aI$ , where $S$ is the skew-symmetric matrix of digraph $D$ , and satisfy the following conditions?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

Why $S^TS=aI$ , where $S$ is the skew-symmetric matrix  of digraph $D$ , the eigenvalues $v_i$ of $S$ satisfy  $|v_i|^2=a$ for all $i=1,...,n$ and the underlying undirected graph $G_D$ of $D$ is $a$-regular?